# Styles Code Wrong

Tags: android

Can anybody help with this code I just don't know where I am going wrong.
Don't know what its is with android styles and themes. But is it me or is the android example on style and theme not all that.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/684/new1ev.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/new2ci.png/

Comment: What are you asking? What's wrong with your xml?

Comment: -1 for linking to screenshots of code.

Comment: for some reason at the time its wasnt letting me input the code. and i was looking for a quick answer. my bad i should of waited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have duplicate layout_width and layout_height in your styles.xml . Also I don't think it is a good idea to include those in your styles.xml

Comment: sorry i missed that i was on a roll with inputting the code i got ahead of myself.thank you